# How can I change the encoding of files generated by the 'dotnet ef' CLI tool in Powershell Core?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, entity-framework, dotnet-cli, powershell-core

I use the following command to generate the C# (.NET Core 3.1) files from a SQL Server DB (SQL Server 2016):

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold $ConnectionString Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer --no-build  --no-onconfiguring -f -c "MyContext" -o Table1/DataAccess -t dbo.Table1
```

When I run this in Powershell 5.1, the files are encoded in `UTF-8`.

But when I use Powershell Core 7.1.0, the files are encoded in `Western European (Windows)`.

I don't think the `dotnet ef` tool uses the default encoding of Powershell, because the output of `$OutputEncoding` is `US-ASCII` for powershell 5.1 and `UTF-8` for Powershell Core 7.1.0.

I would like to use the `dotnet ef` CLI in Powershell Core 7.1.0 to generate UTF-8 encoded files. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you get the same output if you run `dotnet --version` in 5.1 vs. 7.1?

Comment: Why are you asking? All three encodings use the same bytes for the US-ASCII character range. Are you using non-English characters in the table definitions?

Comment: In fact, how do you know there's an encoding issue at all? A text file has no codepage indicator except the BOM bytes which only tell you which Unicode encoding was used. You can't even tell what codepage was used to produce a file unless you find a character that can't be displayed in another codepage

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen yes, bot are the same. Version 5.0.101.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos There are no special characters in the files. But when I generate the files from PS Core 7.1, git marks them all as modified due to the different encoding and I would like to avoid that.

Comment: How do you know which encoding the files are using? Have you opened them with a hex dump tool and observed a Byte Order Mark in the UTF8 file?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I was using Visual Studio 2019 to compare the git changes. There I saw this information.

Comment: @eddex again, how do you know there's any difference to begin with? If you used git, what's the *actual* difference and why do you assume the encoding changed if the contents are identical? Perhaps the only thing that changed is the BOM mark. That doesn't mean the encoding changed

Comment: UTF8-encoded files aren't supposed to have a BOM, to allow ASCII-only programs to work with them the same way they did with single-byte files. .NET Old (PS 5.1 is a .NET Old application) emitted a BOM though. .NET Core doesn't, making it compatible with other OS (Linux, Mac, Android).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I did a diff of the change and there I was able to see that an invisible character was removed from the start of the file. This seems to be the BOM character indeed. So the question would be, how can I prevent the removal of the BOM?